# Why is it not possible to return Obeservable.of(false) in catch block in canActivate method?

Tags: angular, typescript, auth-guard

I use the canActivate feature to protect some routes (admin). For this case I do use the an `authGuard` class/function:

The issue is, when I try to return an observable of boolean as: **`return Observable.of(false);`**, it doesn't work as expected and throws following Error:

> Argument of type '(err: any) => Observable | Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable) => ObservableInput'.
>     Type 'Observable | Observable' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
>       Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
>         Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike'.
>           Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable'.

I have been searching and found kind of this issue, but not exactly the same. And the provided hint/solution was to use `.throw(err);`

When I change the return to: **`return Observable.throw(err);`**, then the error disappears, but it does not return `false` as It should be in order to protect my route.

I believe it's a type issue etc., but I just can't fix it, so that I keep returning `observable.of(false)`

```
canActivate( next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.userService.getAdminAuth()
        .map( (res) => {
            if ( res === true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ......
                return false;
            }
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            if ( err.status === 403 ) {
                console.log(`403:  ${err.status}`);
                return this.userService.refreshToken()
                    .map( (res) => {
                        console.log(`Res RefreshToken: ${res}`);
                    });
            }
            return Observable.of(false); // protect route!
        });
}
```

Functions in **user.service.ts:**

```
....

isAdminAuthenticated = false;

public getAdminAuth() {
    console.log('Saved token: ' + localStorage.getItem('ac_token') );
    if ( this.isAdminAuthenticated === true ) {
        return Observable.of(true);
    } else {
        return this.http.get(
           'URL', { 
              headers: new HttpHeaders({"Accept": "application/json"}), 
              withCredentials: true, 
              observe: "response" 
           }
        )
        .map((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                this.isAdminAuthenticated = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
            return false;
        });
    }
}


refreshToken() {
    return this.http.get(
        'URL', 
        { 
            headers: new HttpHeaders(
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('ac_token')
                }
            ), 
            withCredentials: true, 
            observe: "response" 
        }
    )
}
```

On the other hand, if I change `refreshToken` function to:

```
refreshToken() {
        return this._http.get(
            'URL', 
            { 
                headers: new HttpHeaders(
                    {
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('ac_token')
                    }
                ), 
                withCredentials: true, 
                observe: "response" 
            }
        ).map( (res) => {
            console.log(`Res: ${JSON.stringify(res)}` );
        }), (err) => {
            console.log(`Err: ${JSON.stringify(err)}` );
        };
}
```

Then the error says:

> ERROR in src/app/admin.guard.ts(38,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise | Observable'.
>     Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>       Type 'boolean | {}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>   src/app/service.guard.ts: error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type '(err: any) => boolean'.

Comment: Shouldn't you also return `false` inside `return this.userService.refreshToken()
                    .map()` in your `catch`?

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue. Have been trying it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're supposed to use `return Observable.throw(false)`. `of` is a success, `throw` is an error.

Comment: Did help and it prevents the error to occur. but when I enhance the `refreshToken` function to: `refreshToken() { return this.http.get( 'URL',  {  headers: new HttpHeaders( { "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization" : "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('ac_token') } ),   withCredentials: true,  observe: "response"  }
        ).map( (res) => { console.log(`Res: ${JSON.stringify(res)}` );
        }), (err) => { console.log(`Err: ${JSON.stringify(err)}` ); }; }`, then I get almost same error and also this one: `Property map does not exist on type (err: any) => boolean`

Comment: Then don't return a boolean and return an actual error ... I was just coping with your code, if you want to know everything you did wrong, you should ask it. And please, edit your question next time, excuse the language but it's a pain in the ass to read comment with code ...

Comment: Don't mind. I agree with you. I didn't want to update the question in order to avoid any confusion. But you're right.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly with: not returning a boolean and returning an actual error? You mean from `refreshToken()` function?

Comment: No, I means from where you use `Observable.throw(false);`. Return the error instead of false.

Comment: I did. But it's not working with the updated `refreshToke()` function using `.map( res () => ....)`. If I don't use `map` in `refreshToken()`, then it works.

Comment: It doesn't work because `map` is now a pipeable operator. Consider using it as such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177161/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-trichetriche).